# Simple SQL query to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT FROM tblMailToSend
WHERE (DateToSend < @dateToSend OR DateToSend IS NULL) AND DateSent IS NULL
```

@dateToSend is passed in as a param

I'm trying to convert this to linq to sql query.

I've got:

```
db.MailToSend.Where(m => m.DateToSend == null || m.DateToSend <= dateToSend)
                    .Where(m => m.DateSent == null)
```

But this is giving the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[tblMailToSend] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[DateSent] IS NULL) AND (([t0].[DateToSend] IS NULL) OR ([t0].[DateToSend] <= @p0))
```

Which is giving the wrong results...

What Linq query would I need to match the correct (first) sql?

Comment: might be being stupid do you just need to remove the equals from the <=?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only different is that in your linq statement you are using `m.DateToSend <= dateToSend` instead of the strict less than in your first sql statement. So change that and everything should be right.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
db.MailToSend.Where(m => (m.DateToSend == null || m.DateToSend <= dateToSend) && m.DateSent == null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be a typo, but your SQL is using < whilst your Linq is using <=. Apart from that your queries look like they should produce the same results.

Answer (score 0):

In the Linq-question you have DateToSend <= @DateToSend (Less or equal) but in the SQL-query you just check <